# Application of Unique Factorisation Theorem in Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

CONTEXT: Proof question made up by uni math lecturer

Suppose you have $x+y=2z$ (where $x$ and $y$ are consecutive odd primes) for some integer $z>1$, and that you need to prove that $x+y$ has at least three prime divisors (that don't have to be distinct).

Is it sufficient to say that, according to the unique factorisation theorem for integers, since $z$ can be expressed as a product of primes (and we already have the factor of $2$ which is prime), we know that $x+y$ has at least three prime divisors?

Or, would you need to do further working to show that $z=ab$ for some primes $a$ and $b$?

Comment: It is certainly not the case that $z$ is always $ab$ for some primes $a,b$.

Comment: Anyway, you don't need the uniqueness part of the Unique Factorization Theorem. The existence part will do.

Comment: No. Knowing that $2z$ is even only tells you that $z$ is… a natural. A correct proof would be to show that $z=ab$, where $a,b$ are at least $2$ (but don't need to be primes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$z$ is strictly between $x$ and $y$, hence, not a prime.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it sufficient to say that, according to the unique factorisation
>   theorem for integers, since $z$ can be expressed as a product of
>   primes (and we already have the factor of $2$ which is prime), we know
>   that $x+y$ has at least three prime divisors?

No, that's not enough. In fact, how do you know $z$ is not prime?

To prove $z$ is not prime, consider the fact that $y=x+2$, and therefore, $2z=x+x+2=2(x+1)$. Now, since $z=x+1$, can you conclude that $z$ is not prime?

Comment: How did you get that $y=x+2$? If $x=7$, this generates $y=9$ which is not a prime.

Comment: @RubyPa If $x,y$ are consecutive odd primes, then either $x=y+2$ or $y=x+2$. Without loss of generality, we can assume one of these options.